# Black screen on boot up after upgrade process was interrupted

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I was upgrading from Lubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 when it asked me to change something and these options were offered:

```
1. Use settings as provided by provider(not exact words)
2. Use your settings
3. Compare settings
4. (don't remember this one)

So I clicked D to find out what it's all about and it showed me those "Power button action - poweroff", "Close Lid action - Sleep" etc options and then at the end there was the following
Code:

~
~
~
~
END
```

I tried to select end but somehow it said "something aborting."

I tried to upgrade it again but the command line said there are no new versions so I rebooted and on reboot all I see is a black screen. No login, no nothing.

When I force shut and start again down I see

```
Ubuntu
Advanced Ubuntu option
```

I choose Ubuntu and same thing happens i.e. black screen

Comment: Do you have a backup of your personal files?

Comment: No I did not. The upgrade has always been smooth and this is the first time I tried to do something like this. My curiosity was killing so I decided to press D and boom! Feel like an a$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you enter tty using ctrl+alt+f6 and install lubuntu again, and enter this in the terminal tty:

```
     sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
     grub-install 
     update-grub2
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get upgrade
     sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Doesn't work. Cannot even access tty.